# How to set filename parameter as actual filename

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm wondering how I can set a filename which my function receives as a parameter set as an actual filename.

My Syntax is

```
  std::ofstream file("filename.bin",
  std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);
```

But that will name the file "filename.bin" ofc.

How would I have to write it if I get the filename as parameter and save the filename in a string called SavedFilename. And name the file after the string instead of "filename.bin".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
void foo(const char* filename) {
    std::ofstream file(filename,
        std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);
    // ...
}

foo("filename.bin");
```

Comment: Uhm Yes, but will it not just name the file "filename" since there are quotation marks? filename does not look like a char pointer here.

Comment: And any reasons why you take char pointer over a string here? 
Thanks btw!